# What is the code in Python to get Google count of number of google results for a given query by using paid Google API (Google Custom Search API).

Tags: python

What is the code in Python to get Google count of number of google results for a given query by using paid Google API (Google Custom Search API).

That if you send a word to google to search about it. I want to retrieve the number of results retrieved by Google

Answer (score 0):

From [CSE API Reference](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list)

In the HTTP Response,

> queries.(key)[].count **integer**  Number of search results returned in this set.